# How do I run a mouseclick function only once

Tags: lua, boolean, click, mouse

Solved.. LUA how to latch the mouse click so the light doesn't blink rapidly.
I had to create the latch, latch = 0, and then in the lights() function, compare when latch and ms[3] were different or the same, and what to do in each case.

```
lToggle = {cs=0,x1=1,x2=40,y1=1,y2=40}
ms = {}
latch = 0
function round(num, numDecimalPlaces)
    local mult = 10^(numDecimalPlaces or 0)
    if numDecimalPlaces ~= nil then
        return math.floor(num * mult + 0.5) / mult
    else
        return math.floor((num * mult + 0.5) / mult)
    end
end
function msState(v)
    return {round(v.getMouseX() * 100,1),round(v.getMouseY() * 100,1),v.getMouseState()}
end

function lights()
ms = msState(screen)
  if ms[3] == 1 and latch == 0
    then
    latch = 1
  elseif ms[3] == 0 and latch == 1
    then
      latch = 0
      if ms[1] >= lToggle.x1 and ms[1] <= lToggle.x2 and ms[2] >= lToggle.y1 and ms[2] <= lToggle.y2
        then
          light.toggle()
      else end
  else end
end

function html()
    screen.setHTML([[<html><body>
    <style>
    #test {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: green;
    }
#test2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: green;
    border: 5px solid red;
    }
    </style>
    <span id="test">Test</span>
        <span id="test2"> X:]].. ms[1] ..[[  </br>Y:]].. ms[2]..[[</br>Click State:]].. ms[3] ..[[</span>
         <!--   <span id="test2"></span>-->
    </body></html>]])

    end
```

Then in system.update() is:

```
screen.clear()
lights()
html()
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is solved. I added latch = 0 to the beginning and changed this:

```
    function lights()
ms = msState(screen)
  if ms[3] == 1
    then
   if ms[1] >= lToggle.x1 and ms[1] <= lToggle.x2 and ms[2] >= lToggle.y1 and ms[2] <= lToggle.y2
        then
          light.toggle()
      else end
  else end
end
```

To:

```
function lights()
ms = msState(screen)
  if ms[3] == 1 and latch == 0
    then
    latch = 1
  elseif ms[3] == 0 and latch == 1
    then
      latch = 0
      if ms[1] >= lToggle.x1 and ms[1] <= lToggle.x2 and ms[2] >= lToggle.y1 and ms[2] <= lToggle.y2
        then
          light.toggle()
      else end
  else end
end
```